# How can I implement an interface with a set of values in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, interface

I'm trying to implement an interface in a class like this:

```js
type TLanguage = "TYPE" | "SCRIPT" // Reusable values

interface AnyInterface {
    business: TLanguage
    /** MoreTypes */
}

class Anyclass implements AnyInterface{
    business = "TYPE"
}
```

This throws an error:

> Property 'business' in type 'Anyclass' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'AnyInterface'.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'TLanguage'.ts(2416)

The expected behavior is to whenever I set any value of business outside of the TLanguage scope, it would throw an error... It does work when I set it in a variable:

```js
const anyConst: AnyInterface = {
    business: "TYPE" //✅
    business: "TYPEs" //❌ Type '"TYPEs"' is not assignable to type 'TLanguage'. Did you mean '"TYPE"'?ts(2820)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When a [class `implements` an interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#implements-clauses), it doesn't actually affect the type of the class. The compiler *checks* that the class is compatible with the interface, but it doesn't use the interface as *context* to give types to the class's members. This is a pain point in TypeScript, since people do expect some sort of contextual inference to happen. See [microsoft/TypeScript#32082](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32082) and issues linked within for more information.

When you write `class Anyclass implements AnyInterface {...}`, the compiler acts very much the same as if you had just written `class Anyclass {...}` without `implements AnyInterface`.  If you implement it improperly (or if the compiler infers this) you'll get an error on the `Anyclass` name.

Thus the problem is that `class Anyclass { business = "TYPE" }` causes `business` to be automatically widened from the literal type `"TYPE"` to `string`, since the compiler has no context to do otherwise, and `implements AnyInterface` doesn't change this.

---

And this also means that your solutions here are the same ones you'd have to use if you left out `implements AnyInterface`.  You could explicitly *annotate* the type of the [field](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#fields):

```
class Anyclass implements AnyInterface {
    business: TLanguage = "TYPE"
}
```

or you could use [a `const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to ask the compiler not to widen the string literal (but this will infer `"TYPE"` and not `TLanguage` for the property type):

```
class Anyclass implements AnyInterface {
    business = "TYPE" as const
    // (property) Anyclass2.business: "TYPE"
}
```

or you could make it [a `readonly` property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#readonly) which also hints the compiler not to widen (so it's `"TYPE"`) and won't let you reassign it either:

```
class Anyclass implements AnyInterface {
    readonly business = "TYPE"
    // (property) Anyclass3.business: "TYPE"
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgMgQwHYHMCuCXQLxQEQwCaACgKJ5QA++AygMIBKAksTBQPTtQMRoDOCAEYAbaADcEwtBD4AoWQEskwCACcAZggDG0AIJIQTZWs06oAb1lRrUQfyUy+ALliJUGLFZvsAVD6gAsgD2qhAw4DJQPuyyAL7yWsIIfHxQ+iCJyakKALZgojkQyqnpRioa2tCWNrb2SI4u8MjomDj4RGR4cQlJKWkGmSkATFC5+RCFxf2GxhVm1TZ2fA59uAQk5FDJUFpBSHzAXtacUAAUYKpBkKqgAJTTg3xDAHRLK87tG13xso8PvXwAMyjPIFIrAEoGMomSoWI5QUIIAAme2EIFqy3qq0+nXhJ3Ol2ud3+WUBrzqDRx5DiQA)

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this with `as const`:

```
type TLanguage = "TYPE" | "SCRIPT" 

interface AnyInterface {
    business: TLanguage
    /** MoreTypes */
}

class Anyclass implements AnyInterface{
    business = "TYPE" as const
}
```